# Is the "filtered lookup fields per objects" limit a hard one?

Tags: limits, lookup, filters

In our software we have a somewhat generic object which is extended by douzens of record types (we tried to somewhat simulate object oriented class extension/inheritance).

We now reached the "You cannot have more than 5 filtered lookups per object" limit.

Is this a technical limit or has anyone asked Salesforce.com to increase this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask salesforce to up those limits, contact your account manager and he/she should be able to help you.

Comment: Great. I just opened a case.

Comment: Who schould open a case. We as an ISV because our package cannot be installed into some customer orgs because of that limit? Or the customer himself as he cannot install the package because he reached the limit?

Comment: Aha, it is in a package? I think you should best open a case via the partner portal. I know you can do it without a problem in your own org via your AM, but you should check it with developer support to integrate it in packages

Comment: I'll be curious if you're able to get that built in. Just checked with a colleague who says that we can't do that.  This means your customer experience will be something like find the app, try to install it, fail, contact customer support for increase, wait, reinstall.  Can you architect without the need to increase these for your app?

Comment: As so often the first answer from Support totally ignored this aspect of my question? Asking them often feels like talking to a robot.